# What is the difference between the Instax Mini 25 and the Cheki series?

Tags: film, fujifilm

I'm seriously getting confused.

I'm Googling around for an Instax Mini 25 unit, but I keep getting conflicting results.

- some of the results hint on a distinct difference between the Mini 25 and a Cheki (e.g. Mini 25s come in only white, while Chekis come in a variety of colors)
- some of them show no distinction between the two, as if the two are interchangeable

So here I am. Can anybody tell me exactly what's up with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instax Mini 7s and Mini 25 are also called Chekis, they are the same cameras. This [article/entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20120410045009/http://photojojo.com/store/awesomeness/instax-camera/) on Photojojo might help to clear it up for you.

Comment: Perfect. I should've noticed the Japanese nuance right away, haha. **Fuji** and all that. Thanks!

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan - No problems! Sometimes a second pair of eyes can help.